# Как сделать подчеркивание заголовка

Tags: html, css

[image]

Вот пример, как такое сделать, что использовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: 10px; /* отступ от текста */
}

h1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100px; /* длина */
  background: #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
```